# What's the advantage of removing bayonet from the rifle?

Tags: battlefield-1

In the weapon customization screen you have an option to remove the bayonet. 
What would be the advantage of doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the bayonet removed, you raise your weapon faster.

https://pvplive.net/c/pros-and-cons-of-the-bayonet-in-battlefield-1

> Recoil: Having the bayonet on your weapon will cause your weapon to
>   bounce more as you shoot. Your control will be decently affected by
>   the attachment.
>
> Slower ADS: The fact that the bayonet is on the end of your gun makes
>   it harder to pull up. Aiming down the sights of your weapon will be
>   slower and may cost your life. Especially if you're the run-and-gun
>   type.

Comment: Can you add the pros and cons as a text here to avoid link rot?

Comment: @vartec Some the pros and cons on that page are about doing a bayonet charge, rather than having a bayonet attached. But I've added the two relevant items to my answer -- the two that are just about bayonet attachment.